# When adding accounts, how to enforce password rules, having only the password's hash?

Tags: encryption, password-protection

How can I enforce new password rules (e.g. '12 chars minimum') *on the backend*, when the client sends up a one-way hash? If I used two-way encryption, the client would need the passcode, which seems to defeat the purpose. I'm using a salted hash in case someone intercepts the message, but couldn't they *also* intercept a passcode? This seems like a catch-22.

...but I can't think of anything better. I send down a one-time passcode (which I suppose is fairly safe over SSL), then decrypt the password on the backend and run my checks.

How do the experts handle this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLS is secure if you are using the up2date default policies.
It's not an issue to send over your passwords in clear text and hash them on the server. That's actually what most applications do, even big websites.

You can't enforce password rules on the backend when using a secure hashing algorithm such as argon2 already on the frontend.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I didn't realize TLS was so well trusted. This will be much easier, thanks!

Comment: Not so trusted. The client must be aware that there is no MITM or company certificate or government based certificates that listens all of the traffic. There are many down garage attacks that already [executed](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/64648/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka I agree that TLS isn't perfect and that you still have to trust a CA. However, if a threat actor is able to install a CA on your device, you are already in deep trouble and have more severe security issues to address first.